# What is the name of coordinate systems in multiplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have multiplot:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst
```

I would like to use this command for both graphs (for each graph different range)

```
set obj 1 rectangle behind from first 65, graph 0 to first 656, graph 1 back
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgb "gray90"
```

What is the equvivalent for **first** for the second graph in multiple layout please? How is denoted coordinate system of the second graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read `help coordinates`.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst

   # plot no. 1, all coordinates correspond to this plot
   set xrange [0:2*pi]
   set object 1 rectangle from first 1.2, graph 0 to first pi, graph 1 fillcolor "light-blue"
   plot sin(x)

   # plot no. 2, all coordinates now correspond to this plot
   # overwrite object 1 to replace the blue background by a green one
   set xrange [2*pi:4*pi]
   set object 1 rectangle from first 3*pi, graph 0 to first 10.0, graph 1 fillcolor "light-green"
   plot cos(x)

unset multiplot
```

The "first" in `first 1.2` and "graph" in `graph 0` do not refer to the index of the plot. The "first" corresponds to   the x**1**-/y**1**-axes of the **current** plot, "graph" corresponds to the complete area of the **current** plot.

This is the result:

[image: colored ranges in multiplot]

Comment: Thank you and in case of differen xrange?

Comment: @Archie You can have different `set xrange` commands for each single plot within a multiplot enviromnent. I have updated the answer.